# R PickerGroup-module multiple select

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to figure out a way to slice a data set in R shiny to process further upon that selection.

Until now I've always worked with the usual selectors and sliders and used the updateXYZ-function to generate the values to select from for the next selector.

Recently I've stumbled upon the [**pickerGroup-module**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyWidgets/versions/0.4.3/topics/pickerGroup-module). This modules allows to filter a dataset on features, does it all in one module and allow for filtering in any direction (no pre-defined filter-route I now have). With filtering in any direction I mean for instance filtering on type, subtype, subsubtype works. But also subsubtype, type, subtype if thats how a specific user wants to filter.

There is only one thing i cannot fix in the pickerGroup-module, and that is to allow it to select multiple values per feature. Out of the box it only selects single values. Can someone point me in the right direction to get the pickerGroup-module to allow to multiple values per features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's also a "Selectize Group" module in package [shinyWidgets](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets), in this one you can select multiple values, try it :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

data("mpg", package = "ggplot2")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 10, offset = 1,
      tags$h3("Filter data with selectize group"),
      panel(
        selectizeGroupUI(
          id = "my-filters",
          params = list(
            manufacturer = list(inputId = "manufacturer", title = "Manufacturer:"),
            model = list(inputId = "model", title = "Model:"),
            trans = list(inputId = "trans", title = "Trans:"),
            class = list(inputId = "class", title = "Class:")
          )
        ), status = "primary"
      ),
      dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  res_mod <- callModule(
    module = selectizeGroupServer,
    id = "my-filters",
    data = mpg,
    vars = c("manufacturer", "model", "trans", "class")
  )
  output$table <- renderDataTable(res_mod())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Ah thanks! definitely getting there. Still two things that I wonder about. 1) Why does the pickergroup doesn't just support multiple selections? The 'normal' pickerInput has tons of customization options. 2) Is it possible to arrange the input selectors from the selectizeGroup / pickerGroup vertically so they fit in nicely in the sidebar. Without adjustments they arrange horizontally and are squeezed in when sticking them in sidebar, so nothing is readable anymore.

Comment: I developed them according to my need, I wasn't sure that it would be useful to anyone else. It is entirely possible to add an option to have a vertical layout. You can open an issue here so I don't forget: https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets/issues

Comment: Cool! I've added an issue for the vertical layout.