# r shinyWidgets pickerGroupUI Multiple

Tags: r, shiny

I have a `shiny` app that requires mutually dependent dropdowns. Let's say that someone can filter the data by four different variables but those variables can contain sub-categories of one another. I would like the choices for the more narrow variables to update once a broad selection has been made. After beating my head against the wall for a while, I discovered what seems a custom-made solution to my problem in the `shinyWidgets` package. The `pickerGroupUI-module` functions seems to do exactly what I want it to. The example code, pulled from the documentation is below:

```
if (interactive()) {

  library(shiny)
  library(shinyWidgets)


  data("mpg", package = "ggplot2")


  ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 10, offset = 1,
        tags$h3("Filter data with picker group"),
        panel(
          pickerGroupUI(
            id = "my-filters",
            params = list(
              manufacturer = list(inputId = "manufacturer", title = "Manufacturer:"),
              model = list(inputId = "model", title = "Model:"),
              trans = list(inputId = "trans", title = "Trans:"),
              class = list(inputId = "class", title = "Class:")
            )
          ), status = "primary"
        ),
        dataTableOutput(outputId = "table")
      )
    )
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    res_mod <- callModule(
      module = pickerGroupServer,
      id = "my-filters",
      data = mpg,
      vars = c("manufacturer", "model", "trans", "class")
    )
    output$table <- renderDataTable(res_mod())
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)

}
```

This creates exactly what I need, but I want to be able to select more than one thing per column. The documentation contains a description of `options` that can be passed to the function and within that there is a `multiple` argument which seems promising, but it is not working. It doesn't allow for multiple selections if I do something like,

```
    params = list(
      manufacturer = list(inputId = "manufacturer", title = "Manufacturer:", options = list(multiple = TRUE)),
      model = list(inputId = "model", title = "Model:"),
      trans = list(inputId = "trans", title = "Trans:"),
      class = list(inputId = "class", title = "Class:")
    )
```

Likewise, it doesn't work if I put that code outside of the `params`. I have read through the documentation and gone over the examples on the `pickerInput` function but am still coming up short on where I need to indicate that I want multiple selections allowed.

Comment: My reading of the help files is that you can't do this out of the box. But I hope that I'm wrong because this is much nicer than the hierarchical approach that I've taken with separate pickerInputs in my apps.

Comment: @TravisHinkelman, I failed to find this before, but this question is [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52099851/r-pickergroup-module-multiple-select). I have voted to close my question as a duplicate.